# How to detect HTTP 404 in Android super.loadURL method?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap in Android environment and I would like to know how can i detect/catch HTTP 404 after i perform `super.loadURL(myUrl)` ?

Comment: I have a similar issue and have yet to find a proper solution. I will post if i do, but i second your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to @Override `onReceivedError` method in .

```
public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        // super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity#onReceivedError(int,
     * java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(int errorCode, String description,
            String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onReceivedError(errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        if (errorCode == 404) {
            // show Alert here for Page Not found
            Log.i("log", "Page not found 404");
        } else {

            Log.i("log", "Success");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have done that but i have seen that 404 is not caught in this method but rather only cases where the application couldn't connect to the web server

Comment: @Amit Prajapati Where is errorCode getting set to 404 or 200 etc and then passed into the on RecievedError() method?